# The reverse-order expression "will he", but not in a question

Tags: grammar

I encountered the following sentence in a book:

> Only when he is able to shatter this false belief **will he** truly feel that he deserves the prize he seeks.

and I'm wodnering: why is this "will he" reversed in order (i.e. not "he will") even if this is not a question? Is this some obscure grammar rule I should be aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's quite obscure. Subject-auxiliary inversion usually takes place in questions, but there are a few other situations when it happens- one of which is in emphatic negatives.

Sentences that start with an adverbial with a negative meaning (those that include words like no, never, neither, nor, seldom, rarely, hardly and only) also show subject-auxiliary inversion. This occurs in both formal and informal English:

> Parent: **Under no circumstances** are you going out dressed like that - *formal*
> Adolescent: **No way** am I wearing a tie tonight! - *informal*

You can read more about it [here](https://www.grammaring.com/only-after-only-if-only-in-this-way-etc-not-until) and in section 6c of The Oxford Guide to English Grammar - John Eastwood, 1994.

Comment: Interesting. Is there any explanation of the reason behind why such inversion is used here and how it became this way? Or just an arbitrary rule? How would it affect the meaning if the auxiliary verb didn't swap places with the subject?

Comment: It would be a mistake to think that some grammatical rules are sensible and others are arbitrary. Language evolved naturally, and 'rules' were then put together to explain the grammar to non-native speakers. "How would it affect the meaning...?" It would be ungrammatical to start a sentence with a negative adverbial and **not** apply an inversion inversion.